# How to create multiple views in a web Application based on different logins?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I want to create a web Application which will have different views based on different logins. Example if a manager logins into the web application, he should see the page differently from a normal trainee Login.

I have tried searching on google for solutions but its not helping me to solve my problem.

Comment: What you're looking for is called `ACL`, try googling something like `ACL in web applications`, you will find some good answers 

Answer (score 1):

After getting response from server after user login, you will know type of user like `Manager`, `trainee`, `guest`, based on user type you can simply route user to the designated home page after login is successful.

To get the data from backend you can read [read this article](http://engineering.hackerearth.com/2016/01/29/managing-roles-and-access-control/).